# music cant play and says "need to install plugins"

Tags: installation, rhythmbox, music, plugins, error-handling

my Ubuntu 12.10 rhythm box cant play any songs apart from the ones that were installed with it. it says that no plugins installed and when i try to install them they can not be found

Comment: have you tried installing the ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Answer (score 1):

As dodohjk suggested, install Ubuntu Restricted Extras like this

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Please read about them before installing

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in 13.04, and honestly I still don't know why it happened. I was trying to rip to ogg vorbis, so I highly doubt it could be solved by installing ubuntu-restricted-extras (ogg isn't restricted). The error handler couldn't install the very plugin it was telling me to install though.

It might be worth restarting the computer, as for some reason that seemed to fix that issue.